# Highlight active link in new react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to highlight the active NavLink in react-router v6. It states in the docs (https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) that we need to stop using className and instead go with an inline style function, but I cannot figure it out properly.
Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/router-v6-highlight-active-link-c50bo?file=/src/Home.jsx

Basically the code below shows how the docs tell us to do it, but it seems not to work for me.

```
          <NavLink 
            to='search' 
            className='navlinkbuttons'
            style={isActive => ({
              color: isActive ? "green" : "blue"
            })}
            >
              Search
          </NavLink>
```

All help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Basic gist, `isActive` is a destructured property now, i.e. `({ isActive }) => isActive ? .... : ....` instead of `(isActive) => isActive ? .... : ....`.

Comment: all you have to do is define  the `.active` class, and it just works

Answer (score 8):

NavLink activeClassName prop does not exists anymore in V6. You have to do it manually like followings :

```
 <NavLink
    className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? 'active' : '')}
    to="/child"
  >
    menu 1
  </NavLink>
```

Working example  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pdudcd?file=src/Navigation.js